# "Only if" and "if" direction in Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem

Tags: probability, proof

The title of this question sounds somewhat grand, but all I'm asking is whether there's a typo in the book I'm reading.

The book is "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory," by Jeffrey Rosenthal -- second edition, fifth printing (2011), to be precise.

Page 178:

Theorem 15.1.3.  (Kolmogorov Existence Theorem)  A family of Borel probability measures $\{\mu_{t_1 \, \ldots \, t_k}\colon\; k \in \mathbb{N},\; t_i \in T \text{ distinct}\}$, ... satisfies the consistency conditions (C1) and (C2) if and only if there exists a probability triple $\left(R^T, \,\mathcal{F}, \,P\right)$, and random variables $\left\{X_t\right\}_{t \in T}$ defined on this triple, such that for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, distinct $t_1, \ldots, t_k \in T$, and Borel $H \in R^T$, we have
$$
P\left(\left( X_{t_1}, \ldots, X_{t_k}\right) \in H \right) = \mu_{t_1 \, \ldots \, t_k}\left(H\right)
$$

The consistency conditions on $\mu$ state that we can permute the $t_i$ and H correspondingly (C1), and remove one of the $t_i$ if the corresponding $H_i=R$ (C2), without changing the probabilities.

The author then states that the "only if" direction of 15.1.3 is immediate, and gives a quick outline of (what he refers to as) the "if" direction.

My question:  isn't that backwards?  Isn't it the "if" direction that's immediate, and the "only if" direction that requires an involved proof?

When we say [A if and only if B], the "if" direction is [B implies A], correct?

If so, the "if" direction in 15.1.3 is going from the existence of the probability triple to the consistency conditions, which is straightforward -- do I have this backwards, or is it the book?

Edit: I've checked http://probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/errata2.pdf, no mention of p 178.

Comment: "$A$ if and only if $B$" means $A\Leftrightarrow B$, "$A$ if $B$" means $B\Rightarrow A$, and "$A$ only if $B$" means $A\Rightarrow B$.

Comment: @Zen, yes, agreed -- and that's consistent with what I wrote above, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the author:  it was a typo, and he's added it to http://probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/errata2.pdf.